# How to reduce usage of List in the code?

Tags: java, list, collections, enums, set

I have an EnumSet like this so to shuffle the elements, I need to convert it to List.

```
EnumSet<Fruit> otherFruits = EnumSet.complementOf(CURRENT_FRUIT);
```

Below is my code where I am doing shuffling and adding it original `result` list:

```
private static List<Fruits> getFruits() {
    EnumSet<Fruits> local = EnumSet.of(CURRENT_FRUIT);
    // first element in the list will always be the local fruit so using LinkedList
    List<Fruits> result = new LinkedList<Fruits>(local);

    // I just want to shuffle remoteFruits only
    EnumSet<Fruit> otherFruits = EnumSet.complementOf(CURRENT_FRUIT);
    List<Fruits> remoteFruits = new ArrayList<Fruits>(otherFruits);
    Collections.shuffle(remoteFruits, new Random(System.nanoTime()));

    result.addAll(remoteFruits);
    return result;
}
```

As of now I am using two Lists in the above code and then adding all the elements of `remoteFruits` list to `result` list. Is there any way to do all these things in one List? I just want to shuffle `otherFruits` element only.

Any chance of optimization here?

Comment: Unrelated: you should use `new Random()` rather than `new Random(System.nanoTime())`.

Comment: You could just add `CURRENT_FRUIT` to the beginning of `remoteFruits` after shuffling it.

Comment: @immibis Is there any difference between `new Random()` and `new Random(System.nanoTime())`? Why you suggested first one?

Comment: Well, why would you use a seed less random than it could be? (And: if they come up with an even more random way of generating seeds, then if you're using `new Random()` you get the improvement for free)

Comment: Unrelated: you should use `Collections.shuffle(remoteFruits);` without any `Random` argument (it will already use a Random instance for you, and does so more efficiently because it caches it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can do it if you change the order of actions:

```
private static List<Fruits> getFruits() {
    EnumSet<Fruits> local = EnumSet.of(CURRENT_FRUIT);
    EnumSet<Fruit> otherFruits = EnumSet.complementOf(CURRENT_FRUIT);

    // start by adding and shuffling otherFruits
    List<Fruits> result = new ArrayList<Fruits>(otherFruits)
    Collections.shuffle(result, new Random(System.nanoTime()));

    // now add local
    result.addAll(new ArrayList<Fruits>(local));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will this `result.addAll(new ArrayList<Fruits>(local));`  add local fruit to the top of the LinkedList?

Comment: Don't attempt to create LinkedList in order to shuffle it; that has extremely poor performance. Use an ArrayList.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt no big difference in performance here, since: "If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface and is large, this implementation dumps the specified list into an array before shuffling it, and dumps the shuffled array back into the list". See:(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List, java.util.Random)

Comment: @alfasin I guess with your recent change it will not add `local` to the top of the LinkedList, right? I just tried it.

Comment: I just tried it. And it doesn't work with the LinkedList option as well. I mean it doesn't add  local to the top of the LinkedList. Any idea why?

Comment: @AKIWEB you can do: `result.addAll(0, new ArrayList<Fruits>(local));`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

```
List<Fruits> list = Arrays.asList(Fruits.values());
Collections.shuffle(list);
return list;
```

Don't think it's necessary to have EnumSets, many Lists, or to define your own source of randomness for the shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    EnumSet<Fruits> fruits = EnumSet.allOf(Fruits.class);
    List<Fruits> result = new ArrayList<Fruits>(fruits);
    Collections.shuffle(result, new Random(System.nanoTime()));

    int idx = result.indexOf(CURRENT_FRUIT);
    if (idx != 0) {
        Fruits tmp = result.get(0);
        result.set(0, CURRENT_FRUIT);
        result.set(idx, tmp);
    }

    return result;
```